# classic asp site run very slow on IIS server 10

Tags: performance, vbscript, asp-classic, query-optimization

I am working on a classic asp project. I have deployed it on the window 10 IIS Server (version 10.0.17134.1) on my local computer it's running fine but when I deployed it on my test server which IIS Server (version 10.0.19041.1).it becomes very slow. I have tried some solutions to fix it like to increases the maximum worker processes.it was still slow.
when I disable RealtimeProtection from the window firewall it becomes fast . How can I increase its performance without disabling RealtimeProtection from the window firewall

Comment: RealtimeProtection - this is nothing to do with the firewall, this is (afaik) part of Windows Defender antivirus; my recommendation would be to remove this completely and replace it with a proper AV solution if it's needed.

Comment: Can you run a Performance monitor on the database server to see if your requests are hogging resources? If so, then look at your ASP code because it may look right, but producing the result can be a problem. Use of JOINED tables can be the culprit.

Comment: the EXPLAIN command when added to a MySQL statement will tell you about it, perhaps you can use that to find the offending statement that is slow.  Then post that code so we can see if there is an optimization that can be done.  Update -- no database was specified, but its likely looping through records that is slow.,

Answer (score 0):

If the database is an Access database, convert to MS-SQL as Access can cause such slowness on recent versions of Windows IIS. Access is not recommended today anyway because it has security issues.

If you are using MS-SQL with JOINED tables find another way because despite what some say, JOINED tables can be a resource killer. Run an initial query and then run a separate query based on the first results... very much quicker in most circumstances.